# Why are there redundant rows and columns in my contingency table?

Tags: r, contingency

I am a novice to R, and I am currently learning contingency table. I want to create a contingency table using the data from "`loans_full_schema`"(from openintro) with the "`application_type`" and "`homeownership`" datas. Below is my code.

```
library(oibiostat)

data("loans_full_schema")

tab <- table(loans_full_schema$application_type, loans_full_schema$homeownership)
tab
```

And my outcome is [my outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJje3.png)

Yet, I want to be able to get the outcome as below [wanted outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xysZx.png)
So my question is why are there a "Any" column and a blank row in my outcome?

Comment: Can you give the result of `levels(loans_full_schema$application_type)`?

Comment: > levels(loans_full_schema$application_type)
[1] ""           "individual" "joint"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because there are empty levels in the data.

```
levels(loans_full_schema$homeownership)
#[1] ""         "ANY"      "MORTGAGE" "OWN"      "RENT"    

levels(loans_full_schema$application_type)
#[1] ""           "individual" "joint"
```

You can drop them with `droplevels`.

```
loans_full_schema <- droplevels(loans_full_schema) 

table(loans_full_schema$application_type, loans_full_schema$homeownership)
            
#             MORTGAGE  OWN RENT
#  individual     3839 1170 3496
#  joint           950  183  362
```

You may use `addmargins` to add the totals.

```
addmargins(table(loans_full_schema$application_type, loans_full_schema$homeownership))

#             MORTGAGE   OWN  RENT   Sum
#  individual     3839  1170  3496  8505
#  joint           950   183   362  1495
#  Sum            4789  1353  3858 10000
```